# MYSQL - Return all rows from query with IN operator

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Example WHERE id IN (1, 4 ,53 ,53, 95, 12, 54, 54)
```

I expect to get 8 values from example, but I am only getting 6 values because ID 53 and ID 54 are repeated. Is there any way to get one value for each ID?

Comment: Duplicated values in the `IN` clause are ignored AFAIK.  If you're getting 6 values, then it's because your data only has 6 records which match the distinct numbers in that list.

Comment: This is not how IN is supposed to work

Comment: id is supposed to be a unique id, IN will return the first match.

Comment: I know that duplicated values in IN clause are ignored. I would like to know if there is any query that returns 8 values

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `left join`.  Something like:

```
select e.*
from (select 1 as id union all select 4 union all select 53 union all select 53 union all
      select 95 union all select 12 union all select 54 union all select 54
     ) i left join
     example e
     on i.id = e.id;
```

Comment: If the OP wants to really just _select_ those 8 values, then why would any join be necessary?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . Because the OP wants duplicate rows.  You could argue that `left join` is not necessary, but there needs to be some way to get the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

As you have said, duplicated values in IN clause are ignored. I have solved my problem with javascript.